# HPC sge scheduler info cannot run at host "xxx" because if offers only

Tags: hpc

we use sge scheduler to run a task.
when we submit a task with 4 num_proc to a 8 num_proc compute node, the scheduler info of job shows below
[image]

it seems like the resources of the compute node is enough to run a task with 4 num_proc.But sge scheduler do not think that. what can I do to solve it?

what's the problem with sge scheduler and what can I do to run a task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a configuration in command `qconf`.
`qconf -mc` can enter into a vim editor, which can modify complex attributes.
[image: a part of attributes show]

and change the `num_proc` attribute from `==` to `<=`,
it means when the *`task need resource`* <= *`host offer resource`*, task can run on the host.